# graph traversal performance of azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, graph-databases, azure-cosmosdb

Cosmos DB allows us to store graph data using the gremlin query language.

Are there intelligent algorithms optimizing how the graph is split up among many servers? If not I can imagine some queries being extremely slow do to network latency between the shards.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking, but... you can't think of Cosmos DB in terms of "servers" - it doesn't work that way. This is a massive multi-tenant system, running on a very large service fabric. Your best best is to do some benchmarking on the types of queries you'd typically run, and tune Request Units (RU) accordingly, based on your query costs.

Comment: I will definitely run some tests. It's great that the concept of servers are abstracted away, but if I have a graph that is in the terabytes, I doubt all the data will be living on one physical disk. Meaning that as I traverse the graph, their will be network latency. Sharding graph databases in an intelligent way to minimize this type of latency is a notoriously hard problem with no silver bullet solution. I just want to know if Microsoft has thought of this in their design of the system, as other graph DBs (neo4j, arangoDB, etc) have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is still a bit lacking, but there are some performance considerations for DocumentDb itself.  Namely, setting up a PartitionKey that is adequately granular will split your data across multiple partitions, giving you higher throughput.  You can find more here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-partition-data

Comment: Thanks, so that means it's up to the developer to choose good partition keys based on their domain and how they expect the graph to be queried. That is a reasonable approach I think.

Comment: How does notion of 'PartitionKey' translates in Graph ? Say it's simple property graph with both node and edge having properties and there are different type (label) of nodes possible.